# State of Object, which don't has any attribute

Tags: java, oop, object, instance

We all know state of an Object is value of it's attributes (instance variables), but if class  doesn't has any attribute (no inherited attributes), what would be the state of an Object of such class.

Comment: It would have no state and serve no purpose. In Java, though, all objects have at least some form of hidden state to support language features like `synchronize`.

Comment: It depends on what you define as state. There's an interesting discussion here that may be related to what you're asking: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/128597/can-we-say-objects-have-attributes-states-and-behaviors

Comment: Keep in mind that, as the above link says, there are objects with attributes but not state (immutable objects).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a Java class without a parent class. The default parent would be used, e.g. `java.lang.Object`.

At a minimum every instance of a class has two attributes: a reference address and a `Class` type. Note, not every class can be instantiated. There is also some space used in the `ClassLoader` and any String(s) may (or may not) be interned. This actual implementation might vary slightly on the specific version of the JDK and run-time platform, and additional optimizations can be added by the JIT. However, as a Java developer you are not responsible for this memory management and I would be wary of [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: Elliott, When I said without parent class, I was trying to say that Class does not inherit any instance variable from parent, sorry for confusion.

Comment: @Stifler Implicit attributes, not necessarily variables. Try calling `toString()` on two instances of your class (e.g. the default `toString()` from Object).

Answer (score 4):

There is a word for such objects - **stateless**.

Comment: Sorry I am not questioning on ur answer, but as per Elliott (in above answer), he is trying to say that there will be some implicit instance variable present in every class, so in this case should we class such object as stateless

Answer (score 0):

first thing

any class we write in java will extend `Object` class by default if there is no `extends` written by the developer.

so each and every class will definitely have a parent with no doubt atleast `Object` class.

second

if you dont put any attributes in your class , obviously it will get all the instance variables except private gets inherited to your class.

so it will have atleast `object` state but it will not serve any purpose

Answer (score 0):

An object with no data members and links to other objects is a stateless object and **in this form can hardly be of any use**.

This kind of classes can nevertheless be usefull, because of its methods. It can be...

- a base for a further inheritance. It declares/defines some methods, that could be inherited by derived classes. This class will probably be an abstract class, having no objects at all (although not a condition)
- a service class. It can define some methods, which in nature do not belong to concrete objects but are used by other objects. Like some all-purpose mathematical operations, a service that returns a current time or similar. These methods can be static, so again no instances are needed.

Answer (score 0):

We call those object **stateless**. As the name suggests, they have no state.

Referring to other answers/comments, even though every Java object implicitly extends `Object`, mind that `Object` [has no fields](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/Object.java#Object). So even though every object has a runtime address and class attributes, for all practical purposes you can still consider some objects stateless.

Next, it is definitely **not** true that stateless objects serve no purpose! You can use stateless object for:

1) Grouping functions with similar functionality, similar to `java.lang.Math`, which groups mathematical functions.
2) Passing functionality as a parameter, e.g. `Comparator<T>` can be used to sort objects that do not implement `Comparable<T>`, and it definitely needs no state.

Stateless objects are somehow similar to immutable objects: their state can never be changed and therefore they are always thread-safe.

You may also want to see [JEE Stateless Session Beans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Beans) which differentiate between a converstional state and an instance state.